# Eclipse android Mobile device not connecting after genymotion installation

Tags: android, eclipse, usb

Hey guys I am facing Some problem I am using gionee elife e 7 mini android phone I have tried almost everything to connect it with eclipse IDE I install many drivers but none of them worked but .

But when I installed Moborobo it detected my device and it was working very well untill install genymobile emulator now neither genymobile emulator is working nor my device get detected . I don't want to uninstall genymobile is this common is there any solution please reply

Comment: restart your `adb server`

Comment: how can I restart adb server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your eclipse or go to command line navingate to android sdk tool directory and run following commands.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: Hey guys there was a problem I check that an application which I was trying to run app which is on 4.4w.2 then device not appear and when I created a project in 4.2 jelly bean it detected can anyone tell me how this work